# ajax submit stay on same page + update quantity of product in cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I use ajax to stay on the same page after sumbit form.
and if success I will use ajax load to load other page that has a text about quantity of product.
the problem is the if I first submit, the quantity +1/  second submit the quantity +2 (so total 3 now) /  third submit, the quantity +3 (so total 6 now).
I want it to +1 only

I have 3 page.

product.php page (have a products and button add-to-cart(submit) )
I use ajax here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function() {

        $(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#outside_cart_text").load("<?php echo base_url();?>shopping/ajax_text.php", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                        if (statusTxt == "success")

                            if (statusTxt == "error")
                            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                    });
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
});
```

A page that ajax load if success    shopping/ajax_text.php

```
<?php echo $_SESSION('qty_type'); ?> type <?php echo $_SESSION('qty_product');?>
```

The cart page - the first page(product.php) form will submit to this page. and this page has code logic about add item to cart. so I create session in this page

```
$_SESSION['qty_type'] = $sizeof_cart_array;
$_SESSION['qty_product'] = $total_item;
```

Comment: You can put a flag in your session to check if the product is already available in the Cart or not. Once the product is in the cart, disable the add button

Answer (score 0):

why you want to call on click and on submit as well at the same time ?
Just invoke only on click and handle it.

```
     $(document).ready(function() { 

           $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function() {
```

`$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function(e) {<br/>

              /// code goes here`